# Getting different results from wpcom_vip_file_get_contents, file_get_contents, browser, curl

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

I am trying to load content from json pages at this URL:

http://makeprojects.com/api/1.0/guide/4

When I load via file_get_contents, I'm not getting the parts quantity and type... Any ideas here?

Have a few examples of the different responses at this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/whyisjake/5095391

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not every instance of `type` has a value in the JSON file you're calling. [Your gist](https://gist.github.com/whyisjake/5095391#file-browser-json-L457) does show that you're getting `type` and `quantity` when they are available, though.

Comment: Yeah, weird that they would be so different. I don't think it's an issue of validated response as curl grabs the same thing as the browser.

Comment: I must not understand what the issue is, then. The API link you provided and the results you show in your gist appear to be similar results. Is the gist something other than what your results are with `file_get_contents`?